# How To Change value.replace on "oninput " attribute in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, events, dom-events

I have an input that I want to change in according to a value from a variable in T.S on the attribute `oninput`.
This should only work for English character.

in HTML File:

```
<input class="form-control"
       oninput="value=value.replace(rege,'');"
       [(ngModel)]="value"/>
```

in Typescript File:

```
public rege = '/[^0-9]/g'
```

> error: rege is not defined

Comment: Try `<... #input (input)="input.value = $event.value"...>`. Usually you shouldn't mix forms with direct changes on HTML components value. Have you tried to stick only with `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: Difficulty defining variables in replace on oninput event, This solution does not solve my problem.this issu to avoid the problem of coping and pasting,thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > *in The HTML File :*

   ```html
   <input [(ngModel)]="data" (keypress)="stripText($event)" class="form-control">
   ```
2. > *in The ts File:*

   ```js
   stripText(event) {
      const seperator = '^([0-9])';   
      const maskSeperator = new RegExp(seperator , 'g');
      let result = maskSeperator.test(event.key);   return result;
   }
   ```

> **This solution works But Does not prevent copying and pasting text in textbox**

---